# Chromecast Receiver: Custom XHR Loader

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am writing a custom receiver for chromecast and was wondering if there is a way we can have our own, custom XHR loader functionality rather then the built in `goog.net.XhrIo`?

Basically I need to override the functionality of `goog.net.XhrIo` for all segments/fragments and media files.

I need this to send some beacons back to my servers for analytics.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Media Player Library (MPL), then you can use [skipRequest()](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.RequestInfo#skipRequest) and [setResponse()](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.RequestInfo#setResponse) to achieve what you want to do. Note that the [Host](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Host) class provides a number of overrides for updating Segments, Manifest, License and Captions request info.

Comment: @Corehacker: please add the ticket you wanted to reference in a separate comment (or in your original post) since that is not part of my original response, I think it would be better to not include that as part of my response.

Comment: No issues. Here is the forum post which has more details and reference URLs: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1026

Comment: @AliNaddaf Do you by chance have an up-to-date version of this answer?  It seems the APIs you referred to before no longer exist.  (Or, am I looking in the wrong places?)